# Efficient method to access data across activities

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have a small app that records messages and stores them in an object which implements `Parcelable.`  In the app I have a LOT of messages (about 2000) and it takes a considerable amount of time passing between Activities through `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra`

Is this not the correct usage of Intents+Parcelable?  I've been really wanting to avoid SQLite, but I suppose I'll get my hands dirty if its absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely persist your messages in a database. If you want to avoid all the SQLite hassle check [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/), painless object persistence in your apps using an OODB.